# How to configure MassTransit RabbitMQ to change IBus Username and Password at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit, hashicorp-vault

I need this within the context of an aspnet core application running in Kubernetes that retrieves dynamic (Hashicorp) Vault secrets. Restarting is an option but I rather not use it.

Comment: There is [already an issue for this](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/3021) and it is expected to be part of MassTransit v8.

Comment: Thanks Chris ! Any idea when we can expect v8 ?

Comment: [MassTransit v8](https://docs.google.com/document/d/130PcFTIKQQdJGGDpFbA6-CK9OqkTOmMuaQzwzWO9Id4/edit?usp=sharing)